# Can estimate upper bound of $|p_{i}|$ or $|q_{i}|?$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

> when I  Find the diophantine-equation rational points $$2y^2=x^6-x^2+2$$

I using [Faltings's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem) showed that there are only finitely many solutions,if we assmue that
$(x_{i},y_{i}),i=1,2,\cdots,N$ is solution,and $x_{i}=\dfrac{p_{i}}{q_{i}},i=1,2,\cdots,N$,can we estimate upper bound of  $|p_{i}|$ or $|q_{i}|?$

Comment: This is a very tough sort of problem. You might take a look at Bjorn Poonen's article [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/millennial.pdf) that talks about the challenges of finding rational points on curves. The Jacobian of your hyperelliptic curve has rank 3, and so the method of Chabauty is out. There is an etale double cover of your curve that maps to an elliptic curve over a quartic number field, and one might be able to get elliptic curve Chabauty to work in this context.

Comment: Correction - the elliptic curve is defined over a cubic number field.

Comment: math110, exactly where did you get this problem?

Comment: @WillJagy,when I deal this problem get it:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208662/find-all-rational-solutions-of-this-diophantine-equation